# Is it possible to convert a edge detection output to binary image OpenCV

Tags: android, image, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to convert a text document to a binary image by first detecting its edges and then converting it to a binary image based on output of edge detection.
Can someone help me in this regard.
This is my image after edge detection[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [non-maxima suppression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector#Non-maximum_suppression). That is used to convert a gradient edge image into a binary edge image. It will be difficult to pick out words if the above is the out put of your edge detection. You might need to change your lighting conditions.

From what i remember this is the general algorithm. You want to make sure that you current pixel is greater than two of its neighboring pixels. It is most effective when you pick one of the diagonals. Here i have picked the top left to bottom right diagonal. If you pixel is geater than its neighbors then it is the local maximum and you can set it to one. Otherwise there is a pixel in its vacinity that has a greater value than it so you set it to 0.

```
for(int i=1; i<image.width;i++){
    for(int j=1; j<image.height;j++){
        if(image[i][j]>=image[i-1][j-1] && image[i][j]> image[i+1][j+1]){
            image[i][j]=1;
        }else{
            image[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide me some code for non-maxima suppression in c++?

Comment: 1 is the value of what?
value of black i.e "0" or white "255"??

Comment: 1 is White and 0 is Black in this example. In your implementation you would probably have to change it to 255 for white and 0 for black

Comment: Is it possible to directly denote RGB with single value?
I suppose that output after edge detection is still in RGB value,so can we directly change the pixel color to black or white?

Comment: The image you get back from your edge detector should be a gradient image not RGB, meaning it should only have one channel.